# How do I prevent ViewFlipper from changing images erratically

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

I am using ViewFlipper with Left and Right buttons to switch back and forth between images. After implementing the code below and clicking right button the image will:

It changes instantly to next image > Slide in what was the current image > change back to next image again. I am trying to simply slide current image out left > next image to slide in from the right.

```
res\anim\in_from_right.xml and res\anim\out_to_left.xml respectively:

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="1400"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="1400"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

and java:

```
buttonRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            flippy.setOutAnimation(ChestBurner.this, R.anim.in_from_right);
            flippy.setInAnimation(ChestBurner.this, R.anim.out_to_left);
            flippy.showNext();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in all matters of android studio that are complete mysteries either a restart or update will do the trick.

The above error was rectified after updating all API's in the SDK.